# Ошибки 'неразрешенный внешний символ' в студии 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

После того как поставил обновленную visual studio 2015 preview ultimate.
Появились ошибки странные в проекте. До этого была 2013, там этот же код компилируется нормально и правильно.

1. С чем это может быть связано?
2. В 2015 добавили что то, что меняет объявление таких функций как sprintf, sscanf?

```
1>liblpsolve55d.lib(lp_presolve.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "__iob_func"
1>liblpsolve55d.lib(lp_rlp.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "__iob_func"
1>liblpsolve55d.lib(mmio.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "__iob_func"
1>liblpsolve55d.lib(lusol.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "__iob_func"
1>liblpsolve55d.lib(lp_lib.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "__iob_func"
1>liblpsolve55d.lib(lp_MPS.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "__iob_func"
1>liblpsolve55d.lib(lp_wlp.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "__iob_func"
1>liblpsolve55d.lib(lp_report.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "__iob_func"
1>liblpsolve55d.lib(lp_MPS.obj) : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ sscanf в функции scan_lineFIXED
1>liblpsolve55d.lib(mmio.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "sscanf"
1>liblpsolve55d.lib(lp_MPS.obj) : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _vsnprintf в функции write_data
1>liblpsolve55d.lib(lp_wlp.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_vsnprintf"
1>liblpsolve55d.lib(lp_report.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_vsnprintf"
1>liblpsolve55d.lib(lp_report.obj) : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ vfprintf в функции report
1>liblpsolve55d.lib(lusol.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "vfprintf"
1>liblpsolve55d.lib(mmio.obj) : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ fscanf в функции mm_read_unsymmetric_sparse
1>liblpsolve55d.lib(lusol.obj) : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ vsprintf в функции LUSOL_report
```

Comment: А не линкуетесь ли вы случайно с библиотеками, скомпилированныеми под старую студию? Например, `liblpsolve55d.lib`?

Comment: Да. Видимо скачивал с сайта уже готовые .lib. Сейчас собрал из исходника и заработало. 
А где кнопка преобразовать комментарий в ответ?

Comment: На SO нету. Сейчас напишу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по ошибкам (не находятся стандартные функции наподобие `sscanf`), ваша библиотека `liblpsolve55d.lib` скомпилирована под старую студию. Попробуйте перекомпилировать библиотеку.

Библиотеки, собранные разными версиями компилятора, к сожалению, не совместимы. Проблема в том, что они линкуются с версией рантайма, поставляемой с Visual Studio, а рантайм-библиотеки разных версий несовместимы. (Например, потому, что внутренние функции определены по-разному.)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <cstdio>  // C++
#include <stdio.h> // C
```

Не забыл?